# Check if string contain specific order characters

Tags: c++

I try with the following code to check if the string contain specific characters, but i want to check if this characters in order way this my code

```
string string1= "Amed";
string string2= "Anbhsmegfd";
std::string  x(string1);
if (x.find_first_not_of(string2) != std::string::npos)
{
    std::cerr << "Error\n";
}
```

in my code check if the string contain characters that give string1 but i want to check if find this character in order way 
as an example

```
string1 ="Amed";
string2= "Aehdkm"
```

the string1 found in string2 
but i need the output will be `error` because `e` appear before `m`
how can i make that ?

Comment: Dynamic programming would work. Or recursive backtracking character by character on the smaller string.

Comment: Actually string1 isn't in string2 in the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
string s1 = "Amed";
string s2 = "Aehkm";
size_t k = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < s2.size(); ++i)
    if (s1[k] == s2[i]) {
        k++;
        if (k == s1.size()) {
            cout << "found" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: solve some cases only, if  string1="Ahmed" and  string2="ehAmAhmsed" not found but string2 contain string1 in order way !

Comment: @AhmedElzeiny I just tried it, it says "found". (You could print `i` every time `k` increments to see what happens.)

Answer (score 1):

just write the code.Here is psuedo code, I leave it to you to convert to c++

```
char* s = str2
foreach (char c in str1)
    char *find = indexof(s, c)
    if(!find)
       error;
    s = find
```

ie - look for the first char - if found move pointer to where you found that char and search for next char, else fail